# PostgreSQL copy function escape double quote

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the copy function and have a problem with double-quote escape.

```
COPY (sql) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)
```

sql :

```
SELECT ingredients ->> 'ham' as ham FROM food.

ingredients have JSONB structure.
{
"ham" : "\"Super special ham\"",
.... 
}
```

There is the possibility to escape that double-quote? without brute force methods like `replace(xxx, '"', '''');` to have result as `"Super special ham"`

```
SELECT ingredients ->> 'ham' as ham FROM food. 
 -> "Super Special Ham"

copy (select ingredients ->> 'ham' from food) to stdout with (format csv, header)
 ->  """Super Special Ham"""
```

Comment: I don't understand: the double quote *is* already escaped.

Comment: Somehow it does not work,  `select ingredients ->> 'hame' from food` gives "Super special ham" but `copy (select ingredients ->> 'hame' from food) to stdout with (format csv, header)` gives -> """Super special food"""

Comment: `COPY (SELECT ingredients ->> 'ham' as ham FROM food) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, ESCAPE E'\\');`  from 3  double quote to 2 double quote.

Comment: @mmjan That's the CSV escaping of strings that start with a quotation mark. After all, your data **is** `{"ham": "\"Super special ham\""}` not `{"ham": "Super special ham"}`. Maybe try with `{"ham": "Super \"special\" ham"}` to understand where the quotes are coming from and why they are necessary.

Comment: @Bergi then with escape, the result looks like: "Super \"Special Ham\"" and CSV formatting is malformed

Comment: @mmjan What CSV parser do you use that considers this "malformed"?